# JQuery retriving the next greatest element

Tags: javascript, arrays

in JQuery i m having an array like

```
(1,2,6,8)
```

I have already selected the first element that is 1 which i have saved in a JQuery variable

```
submitterid = 1
```

On clicking a link I am trying to get the next greatest element in the Array than what I have selected in the submitterid..

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

How to find the last element in this array in the code

```
  var previousId;

               $("#previous").click(function (){


            index = submitters.indexOf(submitterid),
                nextId;
            if (index - 1 < submitters.length) {
                previousId = submitters[index-1];
            } else {
                // no ID index

                 // if i am having an array of 1,2,6,8 after moving to 1 from 8 to 6 - 2-1 i am trying to move to the last element of the array
            }

            alert(previousId);




        });// previousId
```

Comment: retaged from jquery to javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Why couldn't you do something like:

```
var arr = [3, 5, 8, 3].sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; } );
var val = arr.pop();
```

Any keep popping the array -- saying that the values don't need to stay in the array.

If you are randomly picking values and you need the next highest, then write the appropriate sorting function.

Comment: You don’t need to specify a comparison function since that’s the default comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

You want a counter:

```
function counter(arr) {
  this.arr = arr;
  this.index = 0;
}

counter.prototype.next = function() {
  return this.arr[this.index++];
}
```

You instantiate it and use it like:

```
var nums = new counter([1,2,3,4,5]);
nums.next() ; => 1
nums.next() ; => 2
nums.next() ; => 3
```

Comment: Wouldn't this assume that the numbers are already sorted low->high? The numbers may be 1,6,3,9,7.

Comment: I don't think the asker wanted to know how to sort; I think he meant they wanted the next largest index. His array is already sorted in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the array.
Try this untested code:

```
// Your test array.
var arrValues = [ "1", "2", "6", "8" ];

var low = 1;
var high = 2;

// Loop over each value in the array.
$.each( arrValues, function( intIndex, objValue ){

if (objValue > high)
  hight = objValue;

if (objValue < high)
  if (objValue > low)
    low = objValue

});

return low;
```

Comment: Justin's code was also a good idea. Sort the array, with highest in the end. Find position of last element, and return last element -1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no need to use any jquery-specific stuff for this, apart from the click event handling, just 'plain javascript' will do;

```
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 6, 8 ];
var submitterid = 1;

$(function() {
  $('a#id').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var greater = -1;
    // loop through array
    for (var i in myArray)
      // find numbers greater than the specified number
      if (i > submitterid)
        // find numbers closest to specified number
        if (i < greater || greater < 0)
          greater = i;

    if (greater < 0) {
      // no greater value found, do something
    } else {
      // next biggest value is in variable greater, do something with it
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is already sorted (see [`sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)), try this:

```
var arr = [1,2,6,8],
    submitterid = 1,
    index = arr.indexOf(submitterid),
    nextId;
if (index + 1 < arr.length) {
    nextId = arr[index+1];
} else {
    // no ID index
}
```

Comment: @Aruna: Replace `index + 1 < arr.length` by `index - 1 >= 0` and `nextId = arr[index+1]` with `prevId = arr[index-1]`.